# error in the code of C#

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

```
while (rdr.Read())         
{
    imgno = rdr.GetString(0);
}
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(imgno);
```

This code generate the error

> `(Error   5   Use of unassigned local variable 'imgno')`

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you declared the variable above this code like so:

```
string imgno;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    imgno = rdr.GetString(0);
}
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(imgno);
```

The compiler can't guarantee that the loop will ever be entered.  Indeed, in any situation where `rdr` returns no records, the loop would be skipped.  In that case, `imgno` would never be assigned a value.  Since the compiler can't guarantee it, the code doesn't compile.

Simply assign a default value to the variable:

```
string imgno = string.Empty;
```